# KeyboardEvent object, determine if it's keyUp or down

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Having a single KeyboardEvent object, is it possible to know if it corresponds to a KeyDown or KeyUp event?
(I know I can keep somewhere the event KeyUp or Down that triggers it but I am looking for a way to assess that independently of the trigger)

Comment: Just look at the object's `type` property? https://jsfiddle.net/57amLho6/

Comment: @Al.G. Uh! looking through the properties at MDN iI missed the introductory paragraph :-). Please feel free to add this as an answer and I'd accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `type` property on the object you've got:

```js
let b = document.getElementById('b');
b.onkeydown = b.onkeyup = function(e){ console.log(e.type); };
```

```html
<button id="b">Button</button>
```